# Automatically function for a form on webpage without click on button

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, paypal

Here is my code for going to the Paypal payment gateway for the item after a click on the "Buy Now" Button, But I want this function to be without even click on the "Buy Now" button, my meaning is when then webpage opened automatically go to the Paypal payment gateway without a click on "Buy Now" button. Is it possible? Any guidance will be very helpful.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://test.com/java.js"></script>

<form target="PayPal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@yahoo.com">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Membership">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1 Month">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="23">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping2" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="handling" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://test.com/Successful_Payment.php">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="receiver_email" value="test@yahoo.com">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<div id="PayPal6" style="position:absolute;left:445px;top:470px;width:134px;height:65px;">
<input type="image" name="submit" src="images/buynow.png" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;" alt="Make payments with PayPal, it's fast, free, and secure!">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Best off converting your form into a GET link and then redirecting to that link.

Comment: @PrestonPHX how exactly?! Please write me

Comment: `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=test@yahoo.com&cmd=_xclick&....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can achieve that by JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function(){
// u should put a name for your form
  document.forms['my_form_name'].submit();
}
```

**EDIT:** You could also submit the PayPal submit button instead of the form:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('paypalButton').submit();
}
```

Comment: I wrote instead of "my_form_name" => "PayPal" but it doesn't work!

Comment: are you sure it is the same name of your form? @Lili

Comment: `window.onload = function(){
// u should put a name for your form
  document.forms['{PayPal}'].submit();
}`

Comment: I put this code on .js file and then I wrote javascript on index php page with the first code I've wrote above on the question but when i reloaded the index php page it didn't redirect to paypal payment gateway at all!

Comment: Your first Javascript code could work now, I added the form name to the Paypal form and then it worked, but I don't want the page open like pop up, and all the browsers blocking the pop ups, I want this function work in the same window not in the new pop up window!